# How do I find my previous posts and replies?

Tags: support, profile-page, history, recent-activity

How do I find my previous posts and replies?

Comment: -1. Unclear. Please provide further explanation about what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You have to click on the button which shows your profile picture with your reputation, badges, etc. in the menu bar (shown in the figure).

[image]

In your profile, you can find a list of your posts.

Answers and questions have their own tab and comments can be found in "all actions" tab.

[image]